# How to connect to a Sitecore instance with Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have reviewed the [GitBook](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting) and the two blog articles ([original](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting/) and [v2](http://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2015/07/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting.html)) about remoting with SPE, but I've not been successful in executing any commands.

Here's an example script I've been trying to get to work:

```
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://local.sitecore
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Item "master:\content\Home" }
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

The script runs without an error, but no text is output.

Things I've tried:

- I have run this same script (`Get-Item "master:\content\Home"`) in the PowerShell Console inside SPE in Sitecore and I get a result.
- I have changed the `-ConnectionUri` to gibberish and confirmed that I do get an error if the URL is incorrect (`New-WebServiceProxy : The remote name could not be resolved`).
- I have changed the username and password, too, but I do not receive an error if they are incorrect.
- I have run `Invoke-RemoteScript` without a session object (passing in the session parameters to that command) and also do not get an output.

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. I was missing a couple of key configuration steps:

### 1. Enable the remoting service in the SPE config

In my `App_Config\Include\Cognified.PowerShell.config` file, I noticed the following (unrelated elements removed for brevity):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <powershell>
      <services>
        <remoting enabled="false">
          <authorization>
            <add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\PowerShell Extensions Remoting" />
            <!-- example to disable specific user from an endpoint: -->
            <!--add Permission="Deny" IdentityType="User" Identity="sitecore\admin" /-->
          </authorization>
        </remoting>
      </services>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Changing that `enabled="false"` to an `enabled="true"` enabled the service. To do that, I added the following patch config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <powershell>
      <services>
        <remoting enabled="true" patch:instead="remoting">
          <authorization>
            <add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\PowerShell Extensions Remoting" />
          </authorization>
        </remoting>
      </services>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### 2. Give access to remote Sitecore users

Add Sitecore users to the `sitecore\PowerShell Extensions Remoting` role in User Manager.

Comment: The security now requires the connecting user to be included in the defined role as of version 4.2.

Comment: @MichaelWest Is there a way to allow access for all administrators (users with the `Is Administrator` checkbox checked in their profile)?

Comment: Yes @Dan, have a look at the github issue for more details. https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/715

Comment: @MichaelWest I take it it's this line? `<add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\IsAdministrator" />`

Comment: Yes Dan. That's the magic catch all. I prefer creating a service api account and adding it to the PowerShell Extensions Remoting role.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a better architectural decision.

Comment: I also write an article you may find helpful on how to set up SPE Remoting Simplified - https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/amazing-sitecore-powershell-extension-remoting-quick-start-to-make-it-work