# How can I rebuild the Solr indexes via Powershell?

Tags: solr, indexing, powershell

I'm attempting to streamline the development environment setup process for a large development team. A lot of the setup process is already automated, e.g. we automatically create a Solr Docker container with all the necessary cores.

We make heavy use of indexes and would prefer to avoid having to ask/demo to the developer to manually rebuild their indexes from the Sitecore Control panel.

I could rebuild manually, or via a Sitecore scheduled task but how can I script a Solr index rebuild, ideally from Windows Powershell?

Comment: you can create a page (rebuildindex.aspx?your-params) that will do indexing and you can call it using powershell script.

Comment: i can use this script inside Powershell IDE module in Sitecore instance. But if we are on powershell IDE outside of sitecore, then the [contentsearchmanager] is not recognized. Any solution to that How to run Powershell scripts to rebuild indexes outside sitecore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rebuild indexes from sitecore powershell you can use below script which will re-index all indexes one by one

```
using namespace Sitecore.ContentSearch

$indexes = [ContentSearchManager]::Indexes

foreach($index in $indexes){
    Write-Host "Re-indexing started " $index.Name
    $index.Rebuild([IndexingOptions]::ForcedIndexing);
    Write-Host "Re-indexing Finished" $index.Name    
}
```

If you want to rebuild indexes using Windows Powershell only then you should enable remoting services first and then execute script

You can refer this link for enabling remoting services - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2665/1606